# Yocto: [meta-realtime] recipe command

Tags: linux, real-time, embedded-linux, yocto, yocto-recipe

linux newbie here. I came across this meta-realtime recipe and built it my qemux86-64 image.
Tried to enter this command "rt-app -t 100000:30000:d -D 1" and the system actually shows

```
[rt-app]<notice> [0] starting thread with period: 100000, exec: 31500,deadline: 100000, priority: 0
```

1. Can i ask why is the exec is set to 31500 when i ran it at 30000?
2. How do i set the priority?
3. Does this recipe install preempt_rt into my qemux86-64 image.